# How to show rss feeds with image using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, feed

How can i show Rss feeds with images using jquery? I tried some very popular plugins like:
 1. [gFeed](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/gfeed/)
 2. [jfeed](https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed)
 3. [zRssfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/)

But nothing seems to support images. What is the best and easiest way to do this? Are there any plugins already available?

Comment: Did my answer not help? Or did I misunderstand your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fetch RSS using simple jQuery ajax call.
Something like

```
$.ajax({
      accept: 'application/rss+xml',
      url: 'http://rss.cnn.com/fortunebrainstormtech',
      success: function(){}
});
```

Using the URL above, I can see that images are return as HTML `<img>` (escaped ofcourse) tags. You just need to unescape them and embed them in your html.

To unescampe simple using the [javascript unescape function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp).

Use Firefox addon called REST Client with the above URL. Add a request header Name=`Accept`, Value=`application/rssxml` to see the returned data yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The zRSSFeed plugin does support images within feeds. By default the plugin will show an abbreviated description. To include images set the 'snippet' option to 'false'.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ticker1').rssfeed('http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list',{
        snippet: false
    });
});
```

For an online example see:

http://zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_images.html